# Selecting the contents of a cell in an FMX Stringgrid in the same way as you can "SelectAll" in an Edit box

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo, tstringgrid, delphi-12-athens

I have a firemonkey application and been using Delphi 10.2 for some years now. Whenever you selected the contents of a cell in a StringGrid it automatically selected the entire contents of the cell, thereby allowing you to start typing and overwriting the contents immediately.
I have just upgraded to Delphi 12 (FMX) and when you select a StringGrid cell it no longer automatically selects the entire contents, meaning you have to swipe over the contents to select them first.
Is there any way to automatically select the contents?

Thanking you in advance

My grid options were set to the following in both 10.2 and 12

```
Procedure TForm1.SetStringGridDefaults(var Grid : TStringGrid);

begin
    StringGrid.Options:=[TGridOption.AlternatingRowBackground,
                         TGridOption.Editing,
                         TGridOption.ColumnResize,
                         TGridOption.ColLines,
                         TGridOption.RowLines,
                         TGridOption.Tabs,
                         TGridOption.Header];
end;
```

I have tried playing around with the `TGridOption.AlwaysShowEditor`, `TGridOption.AlwaysShowSelection`, and
`TGridOption.CancelEditingByDefault` options as well to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I'm on version 11, so this may not be true for you, but with options `Editing`, `AlwaysShowEditor` and `AlwaysShowSelection` set `True` works for me as you whish. In whatever way you move to a cell, existing text becomes selected, the editor is active and if you type, the existing text is immediately replaced with what you type. Exiting the cell without typing or hitting 'Delete' or similar, leaves the text as it was before entering the cell.

Comment: Hi Tom, Many thanks for the advice : I tried it but unfortunately the problem remains. I even tried deleting the TStringGrid object, then re-loading it from the Delphi-12 Tool Palette  but that did not help either.   Thanks again.